# Snap scroll using React, TailwindCSS, Framer Motion with useTransform

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css, react-typescript, framer-motion

I want to achieve horizontall scroll with scrolling using Mouse Wheel. So i did something like that:

```
import Typography from "./Typography";
import { ReactComponent as Iphones } from "../assets/iphones.svg";
import { motion, useScroll, useTransform } from "framer-motion";
import { useRef } from "react";

const HorizontalScrollCarousel = () => {
  const targetRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
  const { scrollYProgress } = useScroll({
    target: targetRef,
  });

  const x = useTransform(scrollYProgress, [0, 1], ["0px", "-2150px"]);

  return (
    <section ref={targetRef} className="relative h-[200vh] -ml-20 -mr-20">
      <div
        // ref={scrollRef}
        // onWheel={(e) => {
        //   e.preventDefault();
        //   e.stopPropagation();
        //   e.currentTarget.scrollTo({
        //     top: e.currentTarget.scrollTop + e.deltaY * 5,
        //     left: e.currentTarget.scrollLeft + e.deltaY * 5,
        //     behavior: "smooth",
        //   });
        // }}
        className="sticky top-0 h-screen flex items-center gap-48 overflow-x-scroll snap-x snap-mandatory "
      >
        <motion.div
          style={{ x }}
          className="flex w-[4250px] gap-[180px] 2xl:gap-[150px] mr-40 items-center  z-0"
        >
          <div className="z-20 pl-8 xl:pl-[169px] snap-start bg-[#070707] ">
            <Iphones />
          </div>
          <Typography
            className="snap-start pl-16 flex-shrink-0"
            description="Boost your brand with our special touch! Dive into bespoke content, SEO tweaks, hashtag insights, and timely scheduling across 8 major platforms. Ready for a chat 24/7? Let’s amplify your digital game together! Boost your brand with. Dive into bespoke content, SEO tweaks, hashtag insights, and timely scheduling across 8 major platforms. Ready for a chat 24/7? Let’s amplify your digital game together!"
            subtext="38,792% roi total"
            href="#"
            textHref="copywriting ssie"
            heading="Our services"
          />
          <Typography
            className="snap-start pl-16 flex-shrink-0"
            description="Boost your brand with our special touch! Dive into bespoke content, SEO tweaks, hashtag insights, and timely scheduling across 8 major platforms. Ready for a chat 24/7?Let’s amplify your digital game together! Boost your brand with. Dive into bespoke content, SEO tweaks, hashtag insights, and timely scheduling across 8 major platforms. Ready for a chat 24/7?Let’s amplify your digital game together!"
            subtext="38,792% roi total"
            href="#"
            textHref="copywriting"
            heading="Marketing Strategy"
          />
          <Typography
            className=" pl-16 snap-start 2xl:snap-none flex-shrink-0"
            description="Boost your brand with our special touch! Dive into bespoke content, SEO tweaks, hashtag insights, and timely scheduling across 8 major platforms. Ready for a chat 24/7?Let’s amplify your digital game together! Boost your brand with. Dive into bespoke content, SEO tweaks, hashtag insights, and timely scheduling across 8 major platforms. Ready for a chat 24/7?Let’s amplify your digital game together!"
            subtext="38,792% roi total"
            href="#"
            textHref="copywriting"
            heading="Marketing Strategy"
          />
          <div className="pr-80 flex-shrink-0 ">
            <Typography
              heading="Want to see more?"
              description="Here's a biref list of all servies we do"
              subtext="click the link below"
              href="#"
              textHref="service list"
            />
          </div>
        </motion.div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default HorizontalScrollCarousel;
```

The thing is I also would like to have something like snap scroll, where component is snapping to left edge of the screen, but I have no idea how to do that.

I tried doing simple container with scroll and had js function (commented in the code). But It had weird stutter and wasn't place correctly on the screen.